# In Maya how can i get Input showing under Channel Box/Layer Editor?

Tags: osx, maya

I'm running Maya 2013 student edition on Mac and 'Input' is missing. I'm following a tutorial in which i can see where it should be.

I've seen a lot of answers to this being "turn on Construction History" but I have tried that, and it doesn't work. Creating objects before and after, restarting Maya each time. Theres also an alternative to delete maya's preferences from the hard drive, but i can't find them.

I'm running Mac OS 10.7.5 Lion and this directory /Users/username/Library/Preferences/Autodesk/maya/en_US/2014/prefs isn't possible. After /Users/username/ there is no Library, that is found before Users.

Going into /Macintosh HD/Library/Preferences/ doesn't show any maya files that i can tell.

Is there a fix to this? or will i have to uninstall and reinstall Maya?

Comment: What "input" is missing?

Comment: We need a bit more information, what Tutorial are you following, what input are you missing?

Comment: If you right click on an object and select *Inputs > All Inputs* do you get anything in the dialog? That means you have construction history and aren't seeing it.  If not, your history is not  getting created

Comment: @ShannonHochkins I'm following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F-hirvikh7w on hands. The _Input_ is under _Channel Box/Layer Editor_. 

When placing an object in, such as a **polygon**, _Input_ shows up. I'm trying to follow his first steps of placing in an **image plane object** and lowering it using _Input_, but it doesn't show up like his.

Right clicking the **image plane object** and selecting _Inputs > All Inputs_ does not show anything in the dialogue box, so it must not be aware of the **image plane object**.

Comment: are you selecting the camera that the image plane is attache to?

Comment: @theo I create the image plane in the Top view port _View > ImagePlane > Import Image…_ Then select the top view port camera through _View > Select Camera_ no Input shows up under Channel Box/ Layer Editor, and my Construction History is on.

Comment: does not sound like user error. Can you turn of 'Dag Objects only` in the outliner and select the image plane directly in the outlines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Accessing your Image Plane (the "Input"):

The "Input" you're looking for I assume is from **4:44** in your video. They made a change to image plane connections in Maya 2013. From the [release notes](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/pdfs/2013/maya_2013_release_notes_en.pdf):

> Beginning Maya 2013, the imagePlane node, which was previously a dependency node, is now a
> shape node.

A few ways way to get to the image plan settings is this:

1. Viewing through the camera which has the image plane attached, select **View > Image Plane > Image Plane Attributes > imagePlane1** (or whatever it's named)
2. Select the image plane in the viewport.
3. Select **Window > Rendering Editors > Hypershade** and select your image plane from the **Cameras** tab.
4. Select **Window > Outliner** and choose the Image Plane there. Looks like it's now on the root rather than under the camera.

Once you have the image plane selected:

1. Open the **Channel Box/Layer Editor** if not already open, by pressing the button in the toolbar or right side collapse bar.
2. Adjust parameters as needed. The one referenced in the video is `Center Y`.

---

## Finding your Maya Preferences:

1. Go to your user folder. Easiest way is generally to select it from the sidebar in Finder:
   [image]
2. You'll notice there is no **Library** here!
3. Select Go > Go to Folder (<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>)
4. Type `Library` and press return.
   [image]
5. A *hidden* **Library** folder appears, in which you can find **Preferences > Autodesk > maya > 2014-x64 > prefs** to delete, if so desired.

Comment: Thank you, I feel like an idiot. I was looking for _Input_ so much I didn't try to adjust any settings such as "Image Center Y" underneath the heading of **ImagePlaneShape1**. Plus, I now know the secret folder search. Awesome, thanks again.